# built-in isight camera on early 2008 macbook air 1,1

Tags: macbook-pro, microphone, webcam

Does the (camera + internal microphone) system use a single internal 2.0 USB interface that connects to logic board?

This seems to be the case according to Wikipedia, and ifixit, even though I cant get 100% sure. Also, is LVDS cable involved here?

Edit: looking at [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+Models+A1237+and+A1304+Display+Assembly+Replacement/855) pictures, from step 19 it seems the internal microphone cable is connected to logic board, while all other input from display (ie. also the USB part from isight) goes through display data cable in step 23

Answer (score 2):

The camera, Bluetooth module, keyboard and trackpad all connect internally via USB. No LVDS cable is required or used by the camera. The internal microphone is connected directly to the audio controller.

Take a look at **About This Mac** from the Apple menu, go to **More Info > System Report**, and look at the devices listed in the USB category to see the various device connections.

Comment: thanks. so is the int mic physically separate from the isight camera? are you on mba1,1?

Comment: are you sure the microphone is connected to audio card and not main board?

Comment: What does your system profile report for USB devices? I don't know about MBA1,1 but every Intel Mac I've used has the mic connected to the audio controller which is located on the logic board (no separate audio card is used on Intel Macs as standard). MBA may be different, only system profiler will tell you for sure

Comment: well, I have no os x installed, but the pictures I linked above seem to clearly indicate a separate audio card

Comment: Referring to iFixit you are correct (although I did say I didn't know about the MBP models, it's the one family of Mac we don't use on campus). MacBooks and MacBook Pros, iMacs and Minis all have the audio controller on the logic board.